# Is the limit of the mean value of a function around a point equal to the value of the function at that point?

Tags: integration, limits, continuity, average

Suppose that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Is the following statement correct?
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{2} \int_{y-\frac{1}{n}}^{y+\frac{1}{n}}f(x) \text{d}x=f(y)$$
If it is, how to prove it? If it isn't, what would be a counterexample?

Comment: no. the limit may be ubdefined at that poibt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. By the integral mean value theorem,
$$
\int\limits_{y-1/n}^{y+1/n}f(x)\,dx=2f(c)/n
$$
where $c\in (y-1/n,y+1/n)$. As $n\to\infty$, $c\to y$ and, by continuity, $f(c)\to f(y)$.

Comment: little overkill, just the continuity and basic properties of the integral are enough

Answer (score 3):

It's true since
\begin{align}
|\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{y - \delta}^{y + \delta}f(x)\,dx - f(y)| &= |\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{y - \delta}^{y + \delta}f(x) - f(y)\,dx| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{y - \delta}^{y + \delta}|f(x) - f(y)|\,dx \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\delta}\sup_{x \in (y - \delta, y + \delta)}|f(x) - f(y)| \cdot 2\delta \\
&= \sup_{x \in (y - \delta, y + \delta)}|f(x) - f(y)| \to 0 \text{ as }\delta \to 0.
\end{align}
We know the last quantity goes to $0$ since that is the definition of continuity at $y$.

Comment: upvoted, but sometimes words are more useful than symbols to learn a subject :) less symbols more words IMO for someone learning the subject to build intuition, which is the most important

Comment: @PeterMüller I agree. The words I should say are: "make the "obvious" estimates".

Comment: What is obvious and what not is very subjective. If you go deeper into a topic and have a full understanding most things will be obvious to YOU but not for others. I could link you several papers where the author claims "this is obvious" at almost all steps and yes, if you know the subject well, they are obvious, but if you don't they aren't. Since you are helping someone in a subject he is not fluent in it will not help at all. If you are writing for someone who is fluent in basic analysis you wouldn't even need to bother to explain this step...

Comment: @PeterMüller Yes that is true. It is only obvious after you see the multitude of estimates established via the triangle inequality. If you have never seen the triangle inequality for integrals before, then it isn't obvious.

Comment: I personally never thought in terms of inequalities. You really don't need to. My thinking would be: close to $y$ $f$ should be close to $f(y)$ since it is continuous and I'd go from there... That's why text is important - it shows how you got there. Then the rest is just explaining your intuition in a precise manner. And that is what you should teach IMO - how you think.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite in terms of $h = \frac1{n}.$ As $n \to \infty, h \to 0^+,$ so we get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}2 \int_{y - 1/n}^{y + 1/n} f(x) dx = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2h} \int_{y - h}^{y + h} f(x) dx$$

Now by basic integral properties we can rewrite this as

$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\int_0^{y + h} f(x) dx - \int_0^{y - h} f(x) dx}{2h} = \frac{d}{ds}\left[\int_0^s f(x) dx\right]_{s = y}$$

where the equivalency of the alternative definition of the derivative can be justified either by L'Hospital's rule or with limit operations. Now, because $f$ is continuous, by the Fundamental Theorem of calculus we have that $\frac{d}{ds}\left[\int_0^s f(x) dx\right]_{s = y} = f(y).$